# Jface ContentProposalAdapter not working on first typed char

Tags: java, events, event-handling, swt, jface

I'm trying to make field-assisting for a Text widget I'm using in a SWT/JFace application.

I have a ModifyListener added on the Text component, and when this is triggered by a ModifyEvent, the setAutoCompletion() method down here and the next method are called:

The problem is that it works only after typing at least two characters. This means that if I have "387" as suggestion, I must type '3' and after that, '8'. The popup appears only with the second '8' character.

After that, it works always as expected, but I don't know why the first time the Text receives the event it doesn't work. I've been looking in "stackoverflow" and in Google but haven't found anything.

```
    private void setAutoCompletion(final Widget widget, final String value) {
    try {
        LOG.debug("Llamada desde " + widget.toString());
        ContentProposalAdapter adapter = null;
        final String[] proposals = getAllProposals(widget, value);
        LOG.debug("Las sugerencias para el widget son: " + proposals);
        for (final String s : proposals) {
            LOG.debug(s);
        }
        final SimpleContentProposalProvider scp = new SimpleContentProposalProvider(proposals);
        scp.setProposals(proposals);
        scp.setFiltering(true);
        if (widget instanceof Text) {
            adapter = new ContentProposalAdapter((Text) widget, new TextContentAdapter(), scp, null, null);
        } else {
            adapter = new ContentProposalAdapter((Combo) widget, new ComboContentAdapter(), scp, null, null);
        }
        adapter.setEnabled(true);
        adapter.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        MessagePanel.openError(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), GUITexts
                .get(Labels.DESTOCK_PROPOSAL_ERROR_TITLE), GUITexts.get(Labels.DESTOCK_PROPOSAL_ERROR_TEXT));
    }
}

private String[] getAllProposals(final Widget widget, final String text) {
    List<String> proposals = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
        proposals = null;
    } else {
        if (widget instanceof Text) {
            for (final Workorder wo : this.openWorkorders) {
                if (wo.getWorkorderId().toString().startsWith(text)) {
                    proposals.add(wo.getWorkorderId().toString());
                }
            }
        } else if (widget instanceof Combo) {
            for (final Workorder wo : this.openWorkorders) {
                if (wo.getDescription().startsWith(text)) {
                    proposals.add(wo.getDescription());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    String[] result = null;
    if (proposals != null) {
        result = new String[proposals.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = proposals.get(i);
        }
    } else {
        result = new String[0];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this has something to do with the code in this link:

http://miscellaneous-niru.googlecode.com/svn-history/r551/trunk/oes/OrderEntrySystem/src/com/oes/controls/SearchTextBox.java

where it reads:
// Work around for Field assistant activating only after
// second character is typed - START

Comment: I have tested doing as the URL sample and it doesn't work. I have also checked the call to the listener and it does work (it gets called and it runs). It's just the ContentProposalAdapter which doesn't get activated on the first typing.

Comment: Did you solve? I've got the same problem!

Comment: @LppEdd This is from years ago. I don't have the code now and can't test it, but try with Othmane's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thanks for your code. I was looking for something like this and I have implemeted it.
When I did, I had the exact same issue as you. I guess it is linked to the ModifyEvent behaviour. I simply changed it to launch on a keyPressed event and now it works perfectly.